# slightly move the home icon in actionbar while sliding menu pops up

Tags: android, android-actionbar, slidingmenu, slidingdrawer

I'm reading [google's official doc](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) about sliding menu/nav menu.

One of the thing I could not implement is to slightly move the home icon on the actionbar. Please refer to the following screenshot - The icon would be slightly moved toward left while the sliding menu is popped up. How to do that?

[image: Slightly move the icon]

Comment: paste your current code

Answer (score 1):

Once you have defined the `drawable` when creating `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, make sure you add the following to your `Activity` for the sliding effect to take place:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html

You supply the drawable to the ActionBarToggle instance and it handles it all for you.

```
new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                    R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                    R.string.drawer_close);
```

It requires a string for open and close, an image for the icon, and the DrawerLayout its attached to.

Heres a class i extends for all my activities in one of my apps. It ensures the drawer works the same across all my activities.

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ActionBarActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    String title;
    View customNav;
    SessionManager sManager;

    public String getActionBarTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
        TextView titleView = (TextView) customNav.findViewById(R.id.title);
        titleView.setText(title);
    }

    public void closeDrawer(int gravity) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(gravity);
    }

    public void openDrawer(int gravity) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(gravity);
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, DrawerLayout layout,
            String title) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.title = title;
        sManager = ((UberApplication) getApplication()).getSessionManager();
        mDrawerLayout = layout;

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this)
                .inflate(R.layout.action_bar, null);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(mDrawerLayout != null);

        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color
                .parseColor("#5385cc")));
        actionBar.setCustomView(customNav, lp);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        if (sManager.getUnreadNotificationCount() > 0) {
            Badge badge = (Badge) customNav.findViewById(R.id.badge_holder);
            badge.setBadgeCount(Integer.toString(sManager
                    .getUnreadNotificationCount()));
            badge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            badge.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {
                    closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
                }
            });
        }

        TextView titleView = (TextView) customNav.findViewById(R.id.title);
        titleView.setText(title);
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                    R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                    R.string.drawer_close) {

                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            };
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
            if (((UberApplication) getApplication()).isFirstLaunchForVersion()) {
                mDrawerLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
                    }
                }, 600);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START);
        }
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```